# Find mean of pixels within a contour/patch matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I am trying to get a significance map based on saliency, for which I have to segment image based on graph cut and find the average saliency with each patch. I was able to segment the image, and obtain contours and the saliency of the original image. The contours show the map of the segmented image. The images are shown below.

[image: The saliency map]

[image: The contour]

I am trying to get the values of the saliency within each patch or contour and get its average. After coming this far, am sllightly stumped, as am not able to think of a clear and easy way of doing this. I checked about activecontour in matlab, but that function seems to do something different. Basically, I would require reference of each patch. Please help me in solving this. : How do I get the average saliency values from the original image (1st one), within the contour maps specified by image 2?

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

By patch, I mean each closed contour region.

Comment: Is there something you have available that can give an ID for each image patch / contour that you have created?  Taking a look at the contour map, I don't know what you mean by "image patch".  Do you mean find the average saliency value in each CLOSED contour?

Comment: yes, in each closed contour region. @rayryeng

Comment: @rayryeng I do not have any other data other than this. is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I'll give you my answer shortly.

Comment: You're welcome.  I also just edited my answer because my initial implementation wouldn't work.  I suspect that if you did it with the way I had it the first time, it would simply return an entirely solid object for your filled in map.  I made a small edit so check it out.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do personally is use `imfill` to fill in all of the "holes" in your contour map.  What this will do is that it will search for any regions where there is a closed contour then fill in those regions with white pixels.  Once that is performed, use `bwlabel` so that it will give you an ID map where independent and connected regions get assigned a unique ID.  Once you have this, cycle through every possible ID, extract those pixels that belong to a region belonging to that ID, then compute the average saliency.

**EDIT:**  If you try to do `imfill` first with what I said above, it may just give you the entire object filled in, and this is probably not what you want.  What I would suggest before you do this is to invert the contour map so that the white lines become black.  Once you do this, perform a logical `AND` operation with the filled in map so you're sure that you are separating the connected regions.

Let's assume you have the following variables:

1. `sal` - Your saliency matrix
2. `cmap` - Your contour map - Assuming this is a binary image.

This is the code I would do:

```
filledCMap = imfill(cmap); % Fill in holes for contour map.
invertCMap = ~cmap; % Invert so that the white contour lines are black
finalCMap = filledCmap & invertCMap; % Mask to ensure we separate the regions
[labelMap, numLabels] = bwlabel(finalCMap); % Extract label map and number of labels

aveSaliency = zeros(1, numLabels); % Store average saliency values here
regionsSaliency = cell(1, numLabels); % Store which region corresponds to a particular ID

% For each label we have...
for i = 1 : numLabels
    map = labelMap == i; % Find the i'th region
    regionsSaliency{i} = map; % Store for visualization
    salValues = sal(map); % Extract those saliency values
    aveSaliency(i) = mean(salValues(:)); % Calculate the mean and store
end
```

What this code will accomplish in the end is calculate the average saliency value for each region that is associated to a unique ID.  If you want to see what saliency is calculated for which particular region, you can do `imshow(regionsSaliency{i});` where `i` is the ID you want.  Showing this, `aveSaliency(i)` will give you the average saliency for the ID `i`.

Bear in mind that I have not tested this.  This is something I would try first.  I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for.